# HDInsight SDK [Microsoft .NET SDK For Hadoop]

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, azure-sdk-.net

As mentioned in this article (Section: Compile schemas using Avro Library) - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-dotnet-avro-serialization/

Download the .zip file with the latest version of HDInsight SDK source code from Microsoft .NET SDK For Hadoop. (Click the Download icon.)

As per instruction, when I access https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/releases
I do not see any download or HDInsight solution file or HDInsight SDK zip file.

Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#readme.md and click 'Download', not 'DOWNLOADS'.

Comment: As mentioned in this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-dotnet-avro-serialization/ I am looking sample code of Sample 6. Do you know exact link?